# Piping output from Write-Host to other command

Tags: powershell, pipe, write-host

I have this script that finds files based on certain cafeterias and write their path using Write-Host. Now, I would like to pipe all of these file paths, and do stuff with those files.

Basically the first script is like this:

```
FindFiles.ps1:
Write-Host "C:\SomeDir\file1.txt"
Write-Host "D:\OtherDir\file2.txt"
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
FindFiles.ps1 | foreach { Copy-Item $_ c:\backup\ }
```

but clearly that does not work. (in reality I want to do something more complicated than just copy do a folder, but that is another problem :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Write-Host` specifically only prints to the console, it does not "return" anything.

If you change your script to just output the strings, it will work.

From:

```bsh
Write-Host "C:\SomeDir\file1.txt"
Write-Host "D:\OtherDir\file2.txt"
```

To:

```bsh
"C:\SomeDir\file1.txt"
"D:\OtherDir\file2.txt"
```